# Scope and threading in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am kind of new to web service calls and threading in iOS. I have a `ViewController` in my app that contains a tableview control. I am populating the table with data obtained via a JSON web service. The JSON web service is called on its own thread, during which I am populating an `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`.

My array and dictionary seem like they are going out of scope since my `NSLog` statement is returning zero for the array count even though while in `fetchedData` the array is fully populated.

Can someone offer an explanation as to why my array and dictionary objects are empty outside of the thread?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *serviceEndpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                 @"http://10.0.1.12:8888/platform/services/_login.php?un=%@&pw=%@&ref=%@",
                                 [self incomingUsername], [self incomingPassword], @"cons"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:serviceEndpoint];
    dispatch_async(kBgAdsQueue, ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });

    NSLog(@"ARRAY COUNT: %d\n", [jsonArray count]);
}

-(void)fetchedData:(NSData*)responseData{
    NSError *error;
    jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    jsonArray = [[jsonDict allKeys]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    for(NSString *s in jsonArray){
        NSLog(@"%@ = %@\n", s, [jsonDict objectForKey:s]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ViewDidLoad` only gets called when the screen first loads. Are you sure `fetchedData` is called before that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `dispatch_async`, that bit of code doesn't block. This means your array count log statement triggers before `fetchedData` is called, so your dictionary and array are still empty. Look at the order of your log statements - you should see array count before your logging of the dictionary.

```
// Executes on another thread. ViewDidLoad will continue to run.
dispatch_async(kBgAdsQueue, ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});

// Executes before the other thread has finished fetching the data. Objects are empty.
NSLog(@"ARRAY COUNT: %d\n", [jsonArray count]);
```

You'll need to finish populating your `TableView` after the data returns (ie in `FetchData:`).

Comment: Yes, this makes perfect sense, but now I am at a loss for how to correct the issue. I need to excecute this on a thread as it may take some time...

Comment: Just call reloadData on your TableView from the fetchedData function.

Comment: You should have some sort of indication on your UI that it's downloading - maybe a spinner or a single cell that reads something like "Fetching data. This might take a minute." That way the user knows something is happening. When `fetchData:` triggers you can call `reloadData`. Or, if the request fails, you can trigger a new display message.

Comment: Move the fetch out of the view controller into a model object. View controllers should never do network access; they should display data found in the model. So the model fetches data as needed, and the view controller just displays whatever the model currently has in it.

Answer (score 0):

The log statement within viewDidLoad SHOULD report that the array is empty as it has not been populated at that time. Calling dispatch_async causes that block of code to be run asynchronously and allows the viewDidLoad function to finish before the block does. That's why you have nothing in your array at the end of viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print count of jsonArray elements before it was populated. Here is what happens:

1. You prepare url
2. You create new thread to fetch some date. Execution of this thread may take some time (depending on connection speed and amount of data).
3. You are accessing jsonArray while thread is executing and fetchedData: was not called

Also, suggestion:
Don't use dataWithContentsOfURL: methods. Better take a look at some networking frameworks like AFNetworking.